# Trouble with scanner, cant manage to read in TSP-file

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to read in coordinates from a TSP-file, they usually look something like this:

```
NAME: berlin52
TYPE: TSP
COMMENT: 52 locations in Berlin (Groetschel)
DIMENSION: 52
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1 565.0 575.0
2 25.0 185.0
3 345.0 750.0
4 945.0 685.0
5 845.0 655.0
6 880.0 660.0
7 25.0 230.0
8 525.0 1000.0
9 580.0 1175.0
10 650.0 1130.0
11 1605.0 620.0 
12 1220.0 580.0
13 1465.0 200.0
14 1530.0 5.0
15 845.0 680.0
16 725.0 370.0
17 145.0 665.0
18 415.0 635.0
19 510.0 875.0  
20 560.0 365.0
21 300.0 465.0
22 520.0 585.0
23 480.0 415.0
24 835.0 625.0
25 975.0 580.0
26 1215.0 245.0
27 1320.0 315.0
28 1250.0 400.0
29 660.0 180.0
30 410.0 250.0
31 420.0 555.0
32 575.0 665.0
33 1150.0 1160.0
34 700.0 580.0
35 685.0 595.0
36 685.0 610.0
37 770.0 610.0
38 795.0 645.0
39 720.0 635.0
40 760.0 650.0
41 475.0 960.0
42 95.0 260.0
43 875.0 920.0
44 700.0 500.0
45 555.0 815.0
46 830.0 485.0
47 1170.0 65.0
48 830.0 610.0
49 605.0 625.0
50 595.0 360.0
51 1340.0 725.0
52 1740.0 245.0
EOF
```

What I want to do is to read all the nodes, their two coordinates and create a node from this. I would like to store them in an arraylist storing lists, like:

```
ArrayList<String[]>
```

My code is currently looking like this:

```
package group12.TSP.tree;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class Tree {
    ArrayList<String[]> storing = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public Tree() throws Exception{
    File file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/burma14.tsp");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    storing = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String nextValue = null;
    //sc.reset();
    sc.useDelimiter("  ");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        sc.nextLine();
        while(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            nextValue = sc.nextLine();
            //st.replaceAll("\\s+","")
            //nextValue = nextValue.replace(" ", "");
            storing.add(nextValue.split(""));   
            continue;
        }

    }
    sc.close();
}

public static ArrayList<String[]> returnScanner() throws Exception {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    return tree.storing;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ArrayList<String[]> storedValues = returnScanner();
    String[] firstLine = storedValues.get(0);
    String[] secondLine = storedValues.get(1);
    for(int i = 0; i < firstLine.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(firstLine[i]);
    }
}
}
```

This doesnt make the things I want it to do, but I dont understand how to implement it, I guess it could just copy the coordinates to a text-file but I want it to work for all sorts of TSPS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made a few changes here.  I read up to "NODE_COORD_SECION" then start parsing ans storing the lines.  Instead of splitting on "" I split on " " and store the values.

```
public class Tree {
    ArrayList<String[]> storing;

    public Tree() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/burma14.tsp");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        storing = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String nextValue = null;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if("NODE_COORD_SECTION".equals(line)){
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    nextValue = sc.nextLine();
                    storing.add(nextValue.trim().split(" "));
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String[]> returnScanner() throws Exception {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        return tree.storing;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String[]> storedValues = returnScanner();
        String[] firstLine = storedValues.get(0);
        String[] secondLine = storedValues.get(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < firstLine.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(firstLine[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
1
565.0
575.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to like remove all the blankspace that will result from this, because when I use firstLine[0] for example, that will just be a blankspace

Comment: Is the input file you are using different from what you gave us? but sure you probably need to storing.add(nextValue.trim().split(" "));

Comment: I really like that solution, I just dont understand how to remove all the whitespace, for example firstLine[0] is nothing more than whitespace to me

Comment: Nice, you are right good sir, thanks a lot for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Use the scanner to move to the next line until it encounters the phrase "NODE_COORD_SECTION". Then the subsequent lines are you data lines. They all conform to the format  so you can use split to get the 2nd and third elements.

Stop reading and storing in your array when you reach a line which states "EOF".

How much do you care about the header of the TSP file? If you want to store this information and check that it is correct against the data in the file, rather than just running to the line "NODE_COORD_SECTION" you would want to look for the line: "DIMENSION" and store the value as an int.  Then check this value against your final total in your ArrayList "storing"

Comment: Thanks for the response, just one question, how to use split to get 2nd and third elements? It's especially that I cant really wrap my head around...

Comment: That's quite straightforward. Call split on your line and pass a space as the parameter and assign it to a String[] : String[] splitStr = nextValue.split(" ").  You are then interested in elements 2 and 3, so splitStr[1] and splitStr[2].  You then want to use these 2 elements as you wish.